# find a string in a dictionary of list and dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a variable dictionary of list and dictionaries that I am trying to iterate over to find a particular value.
The dictionary looks something like this

```
list = { 'foo' : [1,2,3,4], 'bar' : { 'something' : 'value', 'something else' : 'value' }, 'anotherlist' : [5,6,7,8]}
```

The exact structure of this is variable, can be either a list, dictionary, nested, or both.  I have no way of knowing ahead of time what it will be.

I know I will need a generator, but I am failing.  Here is a snipped of code I tried (not my own)

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    print dictionary
    if key in dictionary:
        yield key
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result
```

(I know this is returning key, but I figured I could modify it to value)

But I am getting following:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
> ```

I tried to modify it

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    print dictionary
    if key in dictionary:
        yield key
    if isinstance(dictionary, unicode):
        yield key
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result
```

But that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you calling this function somewhere? how?

Comment: What is wrong with Your solution?  Why is it deficient?  Do you know if part of it works? If so, which part?

Comment: Is the thing you are searching for always either a list item or dictionary value?  Why do you think you need a generator? What do you want the function to return or yield? , please show an example of using the function and explain what the result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here appears to be with the cases where the `dictionary` that is passed in into `find()` sometimes can be just a value, but not even a dict or a list, and this error was thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Try this out:

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict) or isinstance(dictionary, list):
        if key in dictionary:
            yield key
        for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
            if k == key:
                yield v
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                for result in find(key, v):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    for result in find(key, d):
                        yield result
    else:
        if key == dictionary:
            yield key
```

I used this example to test:

```
test_data = { 'foo' : [1,2,3,4], 'bar': { 'something': 'value', 'something else': 'value' }, 'anotherlist' : [5,6,7,8]}

test = find('something', test_data)
for t in test:
    print t
```

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve here, but this would be a starting point I guess.

Comment: You are awesome!! Thank you!